# How to mport many spring config files from a folder in applicationContext.xml

Tags: spring

I would like to in my applicationContext.xml file use  tag to load all spring config files from a single folder.
For example, there is such a file system structure:

some-folder/someBeansDefs1.xml
some-folder/someBeansDefs2.xml

and in my applicationContext.xml I would like to import those files by using something like:

```
<import resource="some-folder/*.xml" />
```

Is there a way to do it? Does import tag supports wildcards?

Comment: Check this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774295/spring-xml-file-configuration-hierarchy-help-explanation. This will help you.

Comment: You can use like the below                                  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-*.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>