# About multiple containers in spring framework

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

In a typical Spring MVC project there two "containers": One created by ContextLoaderListener and the other created by DispatchServlet.

I want to know, are these really two IoC container instance?( I see two bean config files, one is `root-context.xml` the other is `servlet-context.xml`)

If there are 2 containers, then what's the relationship?

Can the beans declared in one container be used in the other?

Comment: They don't create two different container instances, rather two different application contexts.

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7774295/1679863)

Comment: After years later, I have read the spring source code. Now, I can say: 1) yes, there are two instance of ApplicationContext ( each instance will include a instance of beanFactory) 2) the instance of the mvc layer is child  and keep a reference of the parent instance. 3) beans in parent instance can be used by child, but beans in child cannot be used by parent.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

From the [Spring Official Website](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-basics):

> The interface `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext`
>   represents the Spring IoC container and is responsible for
>   instantiating, configuring, and assembling the aforementioned beans.
>   The container gets its instructions on what objects to instantiate,
>   configure, and assemble by reading configuration metadata. The
>   configuration metadata is represented in XML, Java annotations, or
>   Java code.

Again from official Doc:

> In the Web MVC framework, each DispatcherServlet has its own
>   WebApplicationContext, which inherits all the beans already defined in
>   the root WebApplicationContext. These inherited beans can be
>   overridden in the servlet-specific scope, and you can define new
>   scope-specific beans local to a given Servlet instance.

Now coming to your Question, as is stated [here](http://www.codesenior.com/en/tutorial/Spring-ContextLoaderListener-And-DispatcherServlet-Concepts):

> In Spring Web Applications, there are two types of container, each of
>   which is configured and initialized differently. One is the
>   “Application Context” and the other is the “Web Application Context”. 
>   Lets first talk about the “Application Context”. Application Context
>   is the container initialized by a ContextLoaderListener or
>   ContextLoaderServlet defined in the web.xml and the configuration
>   would look something like this:
>
> ```
> <listener>
>      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
> </listener>
>
> <context-param>
>      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
>      <param-value>classpath:*-context.xml</param-value>
> </context-param>
> ```
>
> In the above configuration, I am asking spring to load all files from
>   the classpath that match *-context.xml and create an Application
>   Context from it. This context might, for instance, contain components
>   such as middle-tier transactional services, data access objects, or
>   other objects that you might want to use (and re-use) across the
>   application. There will be one application context per application.
>
> The other context is the “WebApplicationContext” which is the child
>   context of the application context. Each DispatcherServlet defined in
>   a Spring web application will have an associated
>   WebApplicationContext. The initialization of the WebApplicationContext
>   happens like this:
>
> ```
> <servlet>
>       <servlet-name>platform-services</servlet-name>
>       <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
>       <init-param>
>             <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
>             <param-value>classpath:platform-services-servlet.xml</param-value>
>       </init-param>
>       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
> </servlet>
> ```
>
> You provide the name of the spring configuration file as a servlet
>   initialization parameter. What is important to remember here is that
>   the name of the XML must be of the form -servlet. xml.
>   In this example, the name of the servlet is platform-services
>   therefore the name of our XML must be platform-service-servlet.xml.
>   Whatever beans are available in the ApplicationContext can be referred
>   to from each WebApplicationContext. It is a best practice to keep a
>   clear separation between middle-tier services such as business logic
>   components and data access classes  (that are typically defined in the
>   ApplicationContext) and web- related components such as controllers
>   and view resolvers  (that are defined in the WebApplicationContext per
>   Dispatcher Servlet).

Check these links

[Difference between applicationContext.xml and spring-servlet.xml in Spring Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-xml-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring)

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-basics

Comment: As a reminder, please properly quote and link any sources you copy wording from. I've done that in the above, but make sure you do this in the future.

Comment: can you please provide example of,  as you said,  `It is a best practice to keep a clear separation between middle-tier services...`

Answer (score 5):

There aren't two separate containers created. Typically, you want spring to instantiate the object declared in the servlet-context.xml when the object is required. So, you map the servlet-context.xml configuration file to the Dispatcher Servlet i.e. you want to initialize the object when a request hits the dispatcher servlet.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Where as, if you want to initialize the object and perform action when the context is being loaded you would declare the configuration file with in the `context-param` tags of your deployment descriptor.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

You could test this out by writing by declaring separate beans in the servlet-context.xml and  root-context.xml and then, autowiring them in a custom Context Loader Listener class. You would find only the root-context instances are initialized and servlet-context beans are null.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

- `ApplicationContext` a registry of components (beans).
- `ApplicationContext` defines the beans that are shared among all the servlets i.e. root context configuration for every web application.
- `spring*-servlet.xml` defines the beans that are related `WebApplicationContexts` here `DispatcherServlet`.
- Spring container can have either single or multiple `WebApplicationContexts`.

Answer (score 1):

Spring MVC have atleast 2 container -

1. Application Context declared by

   ```
   <context-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
   ```
2. Servlet context declared by -

   ```
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
           <param-value>servlet-context.xml</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   ```

And a web application can define any number of `DispatcherServlet`'s. Each servlet will operate in its own namespace, loading its own application context with mappings, handlers, etc. Only the root application context as loaded by `ContextLoaderListener`, if any, will be shared. Thus can have any number of child containers.