# Spring - application Initialized twice?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web-applications, initialization

When I starts to run my spring application my tomcat , the `ContextRefreshedEvent` fires twice. Please see the StackTrace.

```
Dec 20, 2013 6:07:56 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:SpringValidations' did not find a matching property.
Dec 20, 2013 6:07:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;.;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/lib/i386;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;F:\sub\svn\bin;%DERBY_HOME%\bin;D:\Lal\Lab\SW\apache-maven-3.0.4/bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin;;F:\Eclipse\sts-2.9.2.RELEASE;
Dec 20, 2013 6:07:56 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Dec 20, 2013 6:07:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 289 ms
Dec 20, 2013 6:07:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 20, 2013 6:07:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.16
Dec 20, 2013 6:07:56 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(F:\anand\Spring_Training\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\SpringValidations\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Dec 20, 2013 6:07:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
INFO: The listener "org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
Dec 20, 2013 6:07:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
INFO: The listener "org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
Dec 20, 2013 6:07:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
INFO: The listener "org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
Dec 20, 2013 6:07:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
INFO: The listener "org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 108 and column 11
log4j:WARN The content of element type "logger" must match "(param*,level?,appender-ref*)".
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 114 and column 11
log4j:WARN The content of element type "logger" must match "(param*,level?,appender-ref*)".
Dec 20, 2013 6:07:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

--------------- Context Refreshed -----------------
:::::::::::::::::::::::: Now you can Start the Server Initialization ! :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Dec 20, 2013 6:07:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Set web app root system property: 'webapp.root' = [F:\anand\Spring_Training\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\SpringValidations\]
Dec 20, 2013 6:07:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing log4j from [F:\anand\Spring_Training\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\SpringValidations\WEB-INF\classes\log4j.xml]
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 108 and column 11
log4j:WARN The content of element type "logger" must match "(param*,level?,appender-ref*)".
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 114 and column 11
log4j:WARN The content of element type "logger" must match "(param*,level?,appender-ref*)".
Dec 20, 2013 6:07:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'

--------------- Context Refreshed -----------------
:::::::::::::::::::::::: Now you can Start the Server Initialization ! :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Dec 20, 2013 6:07:58 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Dec 20, 2013 6:07:58 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Dec 20, 2013 6:07:58 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/16  config=null
Dec 20, 2013 6:07:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1659 ms
```

My Initializer class will be as ,

```
public class ApplicationListenerBean implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    private String message;

    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("--------------- Context Refreshed -----------------");
        System.out.println( ":::::::::::::::::::::::: " +message+ " :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::");

       // Other stuff like logger Initialization , Server Initailization etc..
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

And my applicationContext.xml will be as ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org./dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>

    <bean id="test" class="com.pointel.applicationListener.ApplicationListenerBean">
        <property name="message"
            value="Now you can Start the Server Initialization !">
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My web.xml will be ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>SpringValidations</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

My dispatcher-servlet will be as,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">


    <!-- Application Message Bundle -->
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <!-- <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages/messages.properties" /> -->
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/messages/messages.properties</value>
                <value>/WEB-INF/messages/mymessages.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="3000" />
    </bean> 

    <!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pointel.controllers" />

    <!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- <context:annotation-config /> -->

    <!-- Resolves view names to protected .jsp resources within the /WEB-INF/views 
        directory -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Shall I know , Why the **--------------- Context Refreshed -----------------** message comes twice ?

**Edit :** I know there are many ways to initialize an spring application. But `what is the best and the efficient way  to initialize an Spring application like logger,Domain server startup to get protocol connection , stating the threads etc... ?`

Hope , you all can understand my question.

Comment: Do you have a Spring MVC specific context XML file too (such as webContext.xml for example)?

Comment: Post your `web.xml` and `dispatcher-servlet.xml` (or whatever that file happens to be called)

Comment: @Will Keeling Please see my edits .

Comment: take a look at class `org.springframework.context.SmartLifecycle`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Its getting refreshed for each context, Dispatcher and Application.  Try running this test:

```
   public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        ApplicationContext context = event.getApplicationContext();
        System.out.println(context.getDisplayName());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.How to make it once ?

Comment: What are you trying to do on application startup?  In one of my applications I load some lists that are shared throughout the whole application.  When the context is refreshed I just check to make sure the lists have been loaded.  Is there any way to determine the state of the operations you want to perform so that you may conditionally execute them?

Answer (score 25):

This seems normal as Spring MVC application have usually at least two contexts, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682486/why-does-spring-mvc-need-at-least-two-contexts).

In this case this application has two different contexts that serve different purposes:

- a global Spring context common to the whole application
- a servlet-level spring context, which contains all the beans associated to a given dispatcher servlet.

A Spring MVC application can have multiple dispatchers, each with it's own context and all sharing a parent context with common application-wide beans.

In each dispatcher context there are beans specific of the dispatcher that cannot be injected in other contexts and neither on the parent context, for example all beans annotated with @Controller.

This ensures that we can inject service and DAO beans defined in the common context in any controller, but we can never inject a controller into a service, or controllers/beans from one dispatcher into another dispatcher, keeping the dispatchers isolated.

According to the log, the first context initialised is the root context, and the second context is the dispatcher context, which is OK.

Comment: **but we can never inject a controller into a service, or controllers/beans from one dispatcher into another dispatcher,** Could you explain what does it mean? How to get access to dispatcher ?

Answer (score 4):

That's very normal. You have an application listener that loads a the context, and you have a servlet that loads on startup and loads the context also. Remove load on startup from the servlet declaration in web.xml. You web.xml will become tike this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>SpringValidations</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>

    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you misunderstood `ApplicationListener`. It is used to listen for each application context events not web app initialization/destruction events. Try using `ServletContextListener` instead.

In web.xml

```
<listener>
<listener-class>com.blablah.StartupListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

StartupListener.java

```
public class StartupListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        System.out.println("--------------- Context Initialized -----------------");
        // If want to get a bean
        ServletContext context = event.getServletContext();
        ApplicationContext ctx = (ApplicationContext) WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(context);
        MyBean bean = (MyBean) ctx.getBean("myBean");
    }
    // Omitted for brevity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two `<ContextLoaderListener>`s declared in your `web.xml`? Try removing one of these.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```