# Spring - how to exclude a particular URL from spring Controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

May be this question has an answer already.But that is an accepted answer.Because it works in web servers only.

My web.xml will be ,

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I want to exclude the **hello.html** from the spring controller.

Also that thing should be work on all servers like tomcat,Jboss,websphere etc..

Is it possible ?Hope I will get a good solution.

Comment: What's the reason for excluding `hello.html`?

Comment: I am using a third party URL.And I don't want to intercept the url.For example only I used the hello.html.

Comment: so, you have annotations to map on the controller? or have configured in the xx-servlet.xml file?

Comment: If possible anyone can answer my previous question here.I didn't get a solution there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704086/spring-application-initialized-twice/20706340?noredirect=1#20706340

Answer (score 1):

How about just creating a new server-mapping point that points to the default servlet before the spring mapping?

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>hello.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Should work for tomcat but possibly it will work for other servers as well.

Comment: Doesn't this *include* `hello.html` instead of excluding it? To the person flagging this answer, please comment and possibly vote down, but don't just flag because you dislike the answer.

Comment: he wanted to exclude `hello.html` from spring controller. This is achieved by "including" it to default servlet that just handle it as plain resource... what's wrong with that approach?

Comment: OK, did not see that. Reformatted in answer. Removed downvote.