# Spring - duplicate ContextLoadListener found?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

My web.xml will be ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>SpringValidations</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


</web-app>
```

But when I start the tomcat I got the message as ,

```
Dec 23, 2013 3:00:40 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:SpringValidations' did not find a matching property.
Dec 23, 2013 3:00:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;.;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/lib/i386;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;F:\sub\svn\bin;%DERBY_HOME%\bin;D:\Lal\Lab\SW\apache-maven-3.0.4/bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin;;F:\Eclipse\sts-2.9.2.RELEASE;
Dec 23, 2013 3:00:40 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Dec 23, 2013 3:00:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 269 ms
Dec 23, 2013 3:00:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 23, 2013 3:00:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.16
Dec 23, 2013 3:00:41 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(F:\anand\Spring_Training\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\SpringValidations\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Dec 23, 2013 3:00:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
INFO: The listener "org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 108 and column 11
log4j:WARN The content of element type "logger" must match "(param*,level?,appender-ref*)".
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 114 and column 11
log4j:WARN The content of element type "logger" must match "(param*,level?,appender-ref*)".
Dec 23, 2013 3:00:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Dec 23, 2013 3:00:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'

Dec 23, 2013 3:00:42 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Dec 23, 2013 3:00:42 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Dec 23, 2013 3:00:42 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/16  config=null
Dec 23, 2013 3:00:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1670 ms
```

How can I get rid out this INFO ?

Is it possible ?Hope I will get a good solution.

Comment: You have asked same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704086/spring-application-initialized-twice

Comment: @R.S Thanks for your reply.But I asked that question for different scenario.The question is just different.

Comment: Check this link https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44423