# Spring Application Architecture Design

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc

**Environment :**

Spring 4

Hibernate 4

MySQL

Spring MVC REST

Issue :

I am writing a simple REST based application for CRUD operations.

The architecture/components is below :

[image]

I have below design issues :

**1.** In Spring Application , the best practice is to have two separate contexts -

**i)**  **applicationContext** : initialised through ContextLoaderListener (for servives abd daoLayerClasses)

**ii)** **webApplicationContext** : initialised through Dispather servlet (for Controllers/view Resolvers)

**2.** However I haven't seen any sample Spring REST based application using BOTH THE CONTEXTS above. Only Dispatcher servlet appraoch is used.

**3.** So , will creating two separate contexts for REST based application as shown in above architecture be an overkill and unnecessary ?

Or It is better to create two contexts separating SPRING REST layer in WebApplicationContext (`@RestController`) and ApplicationContext containing 
  (`@Services`,`@Repository`)

Comment: This might also help explain why 2 contexts are used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682486/why-does-spring-mvc-need-at-least-two-contexts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is totally unnecessary to create separate contexts for your `Controllers` and `Service`/`Repository` classes unless you were thinking of having multiple Dispatchers or something like that. Generally you should keep it simple and have as few contexts as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The answers to this question will be subjective, but as mentioned in other threads and in the [Spring MVC docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) two contexts are typical, but not the only way to do it.

I think the main reason is to separate them is when you have UI and APIs. They may depend on the same backend services, but probably shouldn't have co-mingled beans.