# Does application context injection depend upon the type of a class?

Tags: java, spring

From this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578143/about-multiple-containers-in-spring-framework) it is clear that there are 2 types of context in Spring - one is application context `ApplicationContext` and another is `WebApplicationContext`, and I could have multiple `WebApplicationContext` if I declare multiple servlets using `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`. Correct me if I am wrong till.

Now, `WebApplicationContext` also an interface and extends `ApplicationContext`, then at runtime which would be actual class implementing these interfaces? I read about didn't became clear to me, my ballpark guess is that `XmlWebApplicationContext` could implement `ApplicationContext`, but then what your implementation of `WebApplicationContext`?

Now, suppose I have a controller bean `@Controller` and a respository bean `@Repository` bean, now considering the fact that I have 2 different contexts - one is application context "ApplicationContext" and another is "WebApplicationContext", suppose I did `@Autowire ApplicationContext appContext` in both my controller and repository then would the actual object injection depend upon whether it is controller class or repository class? (*assume that I have different beans defined in configuration files pointed by "ApplicationContext" and "WebApplicationContext"*).